# email intent did not launch when its clicked

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gmail

I am using email intent is my second activity,there's no error but when the button is clicked,the email intent did not launch and return to my java app. Please help me!

This is my `secondactivity.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:text="MAKAN DAN MINUMAN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhitebone"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gado"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gado"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/header">
        </ImageView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tgd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gado Gado"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhitebone"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/gado">

        </TextView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ka"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/plus"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ka">
        </ImageView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tka"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kopi Aceh"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhitebone"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/ka">

        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus2"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:onClick="decrement2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/tka"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/initial_quantity_value"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/minus2"
            />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus2"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:onClick="increment2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/quantity_text_view2"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:onClick="decrement"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/tgd"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/initial_quantity_value"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/minus"
           />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:onClick="increment"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/quantity_text_view"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/order"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/gado"
            android:onClick="submitOrder"
            android:text="@string/order" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and this is my second java

```
package com.example.moveintent;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.view.View;

    import android.widget.Button;

    import android.widget.TextView;


    import android.widget.CheckBox;

    import android.widget.EditText;

    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.text.NumberFormat;

    import android.text.Editable;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;


    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener


{

    private Button btnBack;
    int quantity = 0;
    int quantity2 =0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        btnBack = findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    public void increment(View view){
        if (quantity == 100){
            //show an error message as a toast
            Toast.makeText(this,"You cannot have more than 100 foods/drinks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            //exit this method early because nothing to do
            return;
        }
        quantity = quantity + 1;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }
    public void decrement(View view){
        if (quantity == 1){
            //show an error message as a toast
            Toast.makeText(this,"You cannot have less than 1 foor/drink", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            //exit this method early because nothing to do
            return;
        }
        quantity = quantity - 1;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }

    public void increment2(View view){
        if (quantity2 == 100){
            //show an error message as a toast
            Toast.makeText(this,"You cannot have more than 100 foods/drinks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            //exit this method early because nothing to do
            return;
        }
        quantity2 = quantity2 + 1;
        displayQuantity2(quantity2);
    }
    public void decrement2(View view){
        if (quantity2 == 1){
            //show an error message as a toast
            Toast.makeText(this,"You cannot have less than 1 foor/drink", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            //exit this method early because nothing to do
            return;
        }
        quantity2 = quantity2 - 1;
        displayQuantity2(quantity2);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        // Get user's name
        EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_field);
        Editable nameEditable = nameField.getText();
        String name = nameEditable.toString();

        //get user's number
        EditText hpField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hp_field);
        Editable nomorEditable = hpField.getText();
        String nomor = nomorEditable.toString();

        // Figure out if the user wants pempek
        CheckBox pempekCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pempek_checkbox);
        boolean hasPempek = pempekCheckBox.isChecked();

        // Figure out if the user wants kue gandus
        CheckBox gandusCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.gandus_checkbox);
        boolean hasGandus = gandusCheckBox.isChecked();

        // Figure out if the user wants bongkol
        CheckBox bongkolCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.bongkol_checkbox);
        boolean hasBongkol = bongkolCheckBox.isChecked();

        // Figure out if the user wants risol
        CheckBox risolCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.risol_checkbox);
        boolean hasRisol = risolCheckBox.isChecked();

        // Calculate the price
        int price = calculatePrice(hasPempek, hasGandus , hasBongkol , hasRisol);

        // Display the order summary on the screen
        String priceMessage = createOrderSummary(name, nomor, price, hasPempek, hasGandus , hasBongkol , hasRisol);

        // Use an intent to launch an email app.
        // Send the order summary in the email body.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Just java order for " + name);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,priceMessage );
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the price of the order.
     *
     * @param addPempek is whether or not we should include pempek in the price
     * @param addGandus   is whether or not we should include gandus in the price
     * @param addBongkol   is whether or not we should include bongkol in the price
     * @param addRisol   is whether or not we should include risol in the price
     * @return total price
     */
    private int calculatePrice(boolean addPempek, boolean addGandus , boolean addBongkol , boolean addRisol) {
        // First calculate the price of one appetizer
        int basePrice = 5;

        // If the user wants pempek, add 10000
        if (addPempek) {
            basePrice = basePrice + 10000;
        }

        // If the user wants kue gandus, add 10000
        if (addGandus) {
            basePrice = basePrice + 10000;
        }

        // If the user wants bongkol, add 10000
        if (addBongkol) {
            basePrice = basePrice + 10000;
        }

        // If the user wants risol, add 10000
        if (addRisol) {
            basePrice = basePrice + 10000;
        }



        // Calculate the total order price by multiplying by the quantity
        return quantity + quantity2 * basePrice;
    }

    /**
     * Create summary of the order.
     *
     * @param name            on the order
     * @param price           of the order
     * @param addPempek is whether or not to add pempek
     * @param addGandus    is whether or not to add kue gandus
     * @param addBongkol    is whether or not to add bongkol
     * @param addRisol   is whether or not to add risol
     * @return text summary
     */
    private String createOrderSummary(String name,String nomor, int price,boolean addPempek, boolean addGandus , boolean    addBongkol , boolean addRisol) {
        String priceMessage = getString(R.string.order_summary_name, name);
        priceMessage  = getString(R.string.order_summary_nomor, nomor);
        priceMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.order_summary_pempek, addPempek);
        priceMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.order_summary_gandus, addGandus);
        priceMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.order_summary_bongkol, addBongkol);
        priceMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.order_summary_risol, addRisol);
        priceMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.order_summary_quantity, quantity);
        priceMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.order_summary_quantity, quantity);
        priceMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.order_summary_price,
                NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(price));
        priceMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.thank_you);
        return priceMessage;
    }


    private void displayQuantity(int numberOfFoods) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
                R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + numberOfFoods);
    }

    private void displayQuantity2(int numberOfFoods) {
        TextView quantityTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(
                R.id.quantity_text_view2);
        quantityTextView2.setText("" + numberOfFoods);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_back:
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check blow that might cause your issue:

1. In your provided code, you didn't trigger `submitOrder(View view)` which includes the code for sending email intent; so make sure that when the button is clicked, this method is triggered.
2. If there is no activity component on your device that can handle this intent, and then android system will keep your app running without notifying you about that >>> this usually happens on old emulators that can't even have a Gmail app installed. You can verify this by using else in below if statement of your code

   ```
   if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
       startActivity(intent);

   } else {
       Log.d("Log_TAG", "No activity on the device (email app) that can handle my intent");
   }
   ```

Please let me know if you need further help

Comment: I mean to invoke/call it by just adding submitOrder(whateverIsYourView); inside your button click listener onClick() event

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Zain!

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);

} else {
    Log.d("Log_TAG", "No activity on the device (email app) that can handle my intent");
}
```

The code works perfectly!!